# Can I indent after a line break?

Tags: html, css

I have got only one paragraph with few line breaks. Can i indent text after each?

```
<p>
   Some text</br>
   More text</br>
   More text</br>
</p>
```

I have no ability to put `<p></p>` instead of `</br>` and use `p{text-indent=1em;}`

Comment: Why do you not have that ability to put `<p></P>`

Comment: It's `<br/>` if you're writing XHTML or `<br>` for HTML. But never `</br>`.

Comment: because i get data from DB, and it will take a lot of time to edit all text.

Comment: Looks like you need to do that anyway. Can use regular expressions to do this for you

Comment: How are these <br /> produced ? from editor , saved into datas, from nl2br alike, ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works in Chrome, Opera, and Safari.  Still trying to figure out a solution for IE and Firefox.

This method assumes you know the maximum number of `br`s in your source.  I'm using `</br>` like you did, based on your comment that it's that way in the database.

```css
br {
  content: '';
  white-space: pre;
}

br:nth-child(1):after {content: '\A   ';}
br:nth-child(2):after {content: '\A      ';}
br:nth-child(3):after {content: '\A         ';}
br:nth-child(4):after {content: '\A            ';}
br:nth-child(5):after {content: '\A               ';}
br:nth-child(6):after {content: '\A                  ';}
br:nth-child(7):after {content: '\A                     ';}
br:nth-child(8):after {content: '\A                        ';}
br:nth-child(9):after {content: '\A                           ';}
```

```html
<p>
  Some text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
  More text</br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, because there is no *element* to apply such styling on. The `<br>` element has no content, and it is unspecified whether you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements on them—in practice you cannot.

You should process the data or change the current processing so that whatever is meant to be a paragraph is marked up as a `p` element (and your current `p` markup should be replaced by `div`, or maybe `section`). That way the styling problem becomes solvable (and rather easy).